# The best way to have multiple observer lists in observer pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, observers

I'm using observer pattern to write a simple group chat program.

Group1: A, B, and C        Group2: A and C

A is a sender/subject with two lists, one for Group1 and one for Group2.

Is having two lists in subject class a good way to do this?

Is this violating observer pattern's feature?

A sender can have two groups of observers.

```
public class Sender {

    private List<Receiver> group1 = new ArrayList<Receiver>();
    private List<Receiver> group2 = new ArrayList<Receiver>();
    private String msg;
    private String name;

    public Sender(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void sendMsg(int group, String msg, JTextArea display) {
        this.msg = msg;
        String output = name + ": " + msg;
        display.append(output + "\n\r");
        if(group == 1) {
            notifyAllObservers(group1);
        } else {
            notifyAllObservers(group2);
        }

    }

    public void register(int group, Receiver receiver) {
        if(group == 1) {
            group1.add(receiver);
        } else {
            group2.add(receiver);
        }

    }

    public void notifyAllObservers(List<Receiver> group) {
        for (Receiver receiver : group) {
            receiver.update(msg);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}

public class Receiver {

    public Sender sender;
    private JTextArea display;
    public Receiver(int group, Sender sender, JTextArea display) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.display = display;
        this.sender.register(group, this);
    }

    public void update(String msg) {
        display.append(sender.toString() + ": " + msg + "\n\r");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "too broad."  There's too many what-if questions to ask here first.  Like: is this code multi-threaded?  Please post an attempt at code and the problem you are having with it.

Comment: @markspace please take a look

Comment: Why do you not model `Group`s as objects as well? Each `Group` can have a `List<Sender>` (and automatically registers as observer to each `Sender`). In return, a `Group` can be observed and forwards observable events from its `Sender`s to its observers. This way, you would not need multiple lists per `Sender` and have a more dynamic setup to create new `Group`s of different sizes.

Comment: @Turing85 what do you mean by that....

Comment: Yeah I gotta agree with Turing85 here, `ChatGroup` should be an object which can encapsulate its own observer list.  However code improvements like this are opinion based.  I'll suggest you try the code review site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @desperatecoder what part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @Turing85 I don't understand creating a group object. This is just a simple program to show how to use observer pattern. If there are two lists in subject, is it violating observer pattern?

Comment: @desperatecoder it is rigid design. What to do, if each `Sender` should be in up to 10 groups? Do you then have 10 lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current design is not necessarily contradicting the Observer pattern, but it is rigid. As of now, every `Sender` can be in up to two groups. What if every sender should be in up to 10 groups? 100 groups? To keep this design flexible, I propose to model `Group`s as objects aswell. The idea is that every `Group` is an `Observable` and an `Observer` at the same time. Each `Group` has a `List<Sender> senders`, to which it automatically registers as `Observer`. If a `Group` receives some `Event` from one of the `Observable`s it is registered to, it will forward this event to its `Observers`. The following code is a rough sketch of my proposal.

```
public interface Observer {
  public void receiveEvent(Observable source, Event event);
}

public interface Observable {
  public void addObserver(Observer observer);
  public void removeObserver(Observer observer);
  public Collection<Observer> getObservers();

  default public void notifyAllObservers(Event event) {
    for (Observer observer : this.getObservers()) {
      observer.receiveEvent(this, event);
    }
  }
}

public interface Event { }

public abstract class AbstractObservableImpl implements Observable {
  private Set<Observer> observers = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public final void addObserver(final Observer observer) {
      this.observers.add(observer);
  }

  @Override
  public final void removeObserver(final Observer observer) {
    this.observers.remove(observer);
  }

  @Override
  public final Collection<Observer> getObservers() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(this.observers);
  }
}

public class Sender extends AbstractObservableImpl { }

public class Group extends AbstractObservableImpl implements Observer {
  private List<Sender> senders = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public final void receiveEvent(final Observable source, final Event event) {
    for (Observer observer : this.getObservers()) {
      observer.receiveEvent(this, event);
    }
  }

  public final void addSender(Sender sender) {
    if (this.senders.contains(sender) == false) {
      this.senders.add(sender);
    }
    this.senders.get(this.senders.indexOf(sender)).addObserver(this);
  }

  public final void removeSender(Sender sender) {
    final int index = this.senders.indexOf(sender));
    if (index >= 0)  {
      this.senders.get(index).removeObserver(this);
    }
    this.senders.remove(sender);
  }
}
```

Some remarks on the design:

- The `abstract class AbstractObserverImpl` is not essential. I was just too lazy to repeat code and since `Sender` and `Group` do not inherit from anything else, I let them inherit from `AbstractObserverImpl`.
- It is also not essential that `AbstractObserverImpl` is `abstract`. For me, there would be no point in allowing instantiation of this class since it is missing its actual functionality (the part firing the `Event`s).
- I opted to create an empty `Event` interface. This is arbirtrary aswell. Whether you use `Object`s as events, or enums, or an interface, or a class or a different approach is totally up to you. As I said: this is only a rough sketch.
- The sketch is not `null`-safe. There are quite some possibilites to cause `NullPointerException`s.